# jQuery re-used ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm trying to setup a website that uses PHP but has no PHP on it, so all of the PHP is bridged with AJAX and jQuery. So I'm trying to setup the user system to work on the same bases and to make things easier I want to have some jquery functions that get information from the database. Let's say a jQuery function that gets the first name of the logged in user:

```
function postData(dataString, url, type, callback){
var request = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    async: true,
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Server Responce: " + data.value);
        if(callback != null){
            return callback(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqHXR, textStatus){
        console.log("Server Error: " + textStatus);
    }
});
return request;
}
```

So for example sakes this is the function that runs the AJAX call. It is called as a variable which is **request** which returns nothing. I also have a call back however I don't want to use this all the time if it's avoidable. Below you can see what I want to be able to do.

```
function getFirstName(userId){
    return postData("userId=" + userId, "getFirstName.php", "GET", null);
}

function useFirstName1(userId){
    rndElement.innerHTML = getFirstName(userId);
}

function useFirstName2(userId){
    rndElement2.innerHTML = getFirstName(userId);
}
```

So as you can see I have one function which works with the AJAX function which is **getFirstName** and then I have two which depend on this function to retrieve the first name of the user **useFirstName1** and **userFirstName2**. What I'm trying to achieve is away that when AJAX has got the JSON from the php file it sends it to the **getFirstName** function which would of called it and then that function returns it to it's own calling function.

Now I've read around and I'm sceptical that there is a solution to this problem and I'm going to need to rely on callback and make the same AJAX request multiple times in different scenarios. I'm not going to put async to false as this defeats the purpose of using AJAX in my opinion and we are all working to a faster more dynamic web and this doesn't help.

All I'm looking for is a simple yes (with guidance) or no whether I can do this or not. Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: After you make the AJAX call once, you can store the returned value in a global variable. That way `userFirstName1` and `userFirstName2` can just return that variable instead of making another AJAX request.

Comment: What do you mean by "no PHP on it," ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes...  Basically, you need to leverage the fact that javascript is asynchronous and can use callbacks.  Returning a value at the end of a function will often happen before the call within the body of the method has completed.

```
function postData(dataString, url, type, callback){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "html",  // This needs to be html
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Server Response: " + data.value);
            // check that callback is a function and run it
            if (typeof(callback)=="function"){
                return callback(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqHXR, textStatus){
            console.log("Server Error: " + textStatus);
        }
    });
    // do not return here because it will return before your asynchronous request
}

function getFirstName(userId, callback){
    return postData("userId=" + userId, "getFirstName.php", "GET", callback);
}

function useFirstName1(userId){
    getFirstName(userId, funciton(data){
        // most likely, for html requests, you'll get back responseText
        if (typeof(data.responseText)!="undefined") {
            rndElement.innerHTML = data.responseText;
            return true;
        }

        // well, maybe it returned xml
        if (typeof(data.responseXML)!="undefined") {
            rndElement.innerHTML = data.responseXML;
            return true;
        }

        // give up and just set the response data
        rndElement.innerHTML = data;         
    });
}

function useFirstName2(userId){
    getFirstName(userId, funciton(data){
        if (typeof(data.responseText)!="undefined") {
            rndElement2.innerHTML = data.responseText;
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof(data.responseXML)!="undefined") {
            rndElement.innerHTML = data.responseXML;
            return true;
        }   
        rndElement.innerHTML = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to rely on passing around callbacks to do this if you do not want to update the getPostData function to be `async: false`. The easiest tweak I can think of to get this working would be to update `getFirstName` to take a callback value and just marshal it to the `getPostData` function like this:

```
function getFirstName(userId, cb){
    return postData("userId=" + userId, "getFirstName.php", "GET", cb);
}
```

and you'd simply modify your helper functions to:

```
function useFirstName1(userId){
    getFirstName(userId, function (data) { rndElement.innerHTML = data; })
}

function useFirstName2(userId){
    getFirstName(userId, function (data) { rndElement2.innerHTML = data; })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is achievable this exact way.

The 'postData' and the 'getFirstName' both return ajax objects, you will need to use callbacks or promises.

You will need to do simething like this:

```
function useFirstName1(userId){
     getFirstName(userId).done(function (response) {
          rndElement.innerHTML = response;
     });
}
```

But the bottom line is this: if you use async, then you need some sort of callbacks.

Also you in the original definition of postData you are not using the 'type' and 'callback' parameters.